# Was bedeutet das Verb »rauslassen«?

Tags: meaning, preposition

Ich habe einen Satz gelesen, er lautet:

> Sie können mich vielleicht an einem Café rauslassen.

Kommt die Präposition »an« gemeinsam mit »rauslassen«?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*rauslassen* ist in diesem Zusammenhang ein Synonym für *aussteigen lassen*. Der Sprecher fährt wohl bei jemandem mit (zum Beispiel im Auto) und schlägt vor, dass ihn der Fahrer bei einem Café aussteigen lässt.

*rauslassen* ist eher umgangssprachlich und kommt eigentlich von *herauslassen* (let out).

*rauslassen* fordert nicht unbedingt ein *an*, sondern kann mit einem Ort ergänzt werden. Es wäre auch möglich zu sagen:

> Sie können mich bei einem Café rauslassen.

oder etwas ganz anderes wie zum Beispiel:

> Sie können mich hinter dem Haus rauslassen.

Comment: <Der Sprecher fährt wohl bei jemandem mit (zum Beispiel im Auto) >

was bedeutet <bei> da ?

Comment: @Ehab Es heißt einfach *bei jemandem mitfahren*. *bei* ist eine Präposition und steht hier vor der Person o.ä. bei der mitgefahren wird. Warum ausgerechnet bei kommt, kann ich nicht erklären.

Answer (score 1):

Rauslassen ist kurz und umgangsprachlich für "herauslassen". 
Zusätzlich zu den schon erwähnten Bedeutungen:
Man kann die Katze oder den Hund "rauslassen". Bedeutet das Haustier (mit Bedacht) aus dem Haus laufen lassen. 
Mein Favorit: Die Sau rauslassen. Bedeutet:  Schwer feiern, "let your hair down" , "party hard" 
In meinem persönlichen Sprachgebrauch sehr häufig. Ich selbst sage praktisch nie "herauslassen" sondern benutze nahezu immer "rauslassen". (Sauerland)